# Singleton entity object not persisting changes between 2 .exe

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**I have 3 projects:**

1. Program 1 (Save, using the #3)
2. Program 2 (Read, using the #3)
3. Repo, EF stuff (Save/Read)

**Steps:**

I open the `program #2`, that reads a specifc data and present to the user. The user chooses to do something with a row, like `cancel/delete/update`, the click event opens the `program #1` to update the data, in the end of the update, the program #2 reads again the database to update the `DataGrid`.

**Singleton:**

```
    private static DbEntities _dbEntities;

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden]
    public static DbEntities GetContext()
    {
        return _dbEntities ?? (_dbEntities = new DbEntities(Config.ConnectionString));
    }
```

**Problem:**

The program #2 don't receive the updated data changed by the program #1. I have to restart the program #2 to get the correct data.

### Edit

I only call the GetContext once for each program.

### Edit 2

I'll test with `AsNoTracking`.

### Working with:

```
    public List<sis_program> GetAll()
    {
        return DbExtensions.AsNoTracking(_context.sis_program).ToList();
        //return _context.sis_program.ToList(); //old code.
    }
```

Comment: How does program 1 signal to program 2 that it is finished? Does program 1 run asynchronously, or does it block program 2?

Comment: Program 1 deals with xml files, moving to folders, I just detect when the file got moved to the last folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different contexts in two different app domains, by default your entity framework context uses cache, since the first context didn't update the data it will read cached data therefore will not see the new changes.

To solve you need to eagerly read data again by program 2 to fetch the new changes, try using `AsNoTracking` linq method for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `DbContext` stores cached versions unless you use `AsNoTracking()`.  So whatever happens in one context is never seen in the other context unless you recreate the context, never use the cache, or empty the cache.